# Sequelize hangs up when creating tables

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Im using node.js and sequelize library to create a database. Database is Postgresql.
Running on a server with PostgreSQL 9.4.5 works. Running it on a server with PostgreSQL 9.5.2 doesn't.

Im trying to debug and I see that node hangs up for a while and then at the end it gets a TIMEOUT:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

What is it trying to do?
It has to create a few tables. There around 20 tables.
It creates the first 3 tables. Each time a table is created, for some reason, sequelize run this statement:

```
SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'Tablename' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
```

Always, after the thirth table has been created, everything hangs up until I get a TIMEOUT.

If I login in to the server where the database is installed and run the same statement, there is no problem. The query returns a row:

Where should I look? Could not find anything in postgres-log either. I really have no clue.